# Why does tf.constant give a dtype error if we pass in a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following code

```
a = tf.range(10)
b = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float32)
```

gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Expected tensor with type tf.float32 not tf.int32
```

Although from the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/constant), setting `dtype` means that `tf.constant` is supposed to cast `a` to the specified data type. So I don't see why this should give a type error.

I also know that:

```
a = np.arange(10)
b = tf.constant(a, dtype=tf.float32)
```

does not give an error.

So actually, I'm mainly wondering about what's happening under the hood here.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the source [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e5bf8de410005de06a7ff5393fafdf832ef1d4ad/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py#L68), you will see that `EagerTensor` gets a special treatment. Basically, if the `dtype` of an `EagerTensor` doesn't match the new `dtype`, an error is raised.

Here, `tf.range()` produces an `EagerTensor`. I'm not sure why the special treatment for `EagerTensors` though. Could be a performance related restriction.